# How to display row data as column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to display row values as column values. and also display the final total value at end of the table.

To do that  I'm using the below data set.

[image]

I want to set this data in the column side.

[image]

I used this SQL query to do that. But I don't know how to get Hours Total Column

```
select *   
from 
    (select EMP_NO,SUM(Hours) total
     from Employee_Attendence
     group by EMP_NO) 
pivot
    (sum(total) 
         for WAGE_Type in ('Absence', 'Normal'))
```

Final output should display as below.

```
Select EMP_NO, Absence, Normal, Total
From 
    (select *
     from 
         (select EMP_NO, sum(Hours) total
          from Employee_Attendence
          group by EMP_NO) 
     pivot
         (sum(total) 
              for WAGE_Type in ('Absence', 'Normal'))
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple conditional aggregation should do the trick

**Example**

```
Select Emp_ID
      ,Absence = sum(case when Wage_Type ='Absence' then Hours else 0 end)
      ,Normal  = sum(case when Wage_Type ='Normal'  then Hours else 0 end)
      ,Total   = sum(Hours)
 From  YourTable
 Group By Emp_ID
```

**Results**

```
Emp_ID  Absence Normal  Total
4000    8       32      40
```

**EDIT - If you'd rather a PIVOT**

```
Select Emp_ID
      ,Absence
      ,Normal
      ,Total = Absence + Normal
 From YourTable
 Pivot (sum( Hours ) for Wage_Type in ([Absence],[Normal] ) ) pvt
```

Comment: Thanks for the help
And do you know how to do it same in Oracle

Comment: @Neth Sorry, haven't touched Oracle in decades.

Comment: @Neth, you should use the same logic in Oracle but you need to use column aliases. Something like this should work:

Select Emp_ID
      ,sum(case when Wage_Type ='Absence' then Hours else 0 end) AS Absence
      ,sum(case when Wage_Type ='Normal'  then Hours else 0 end) AS Normal
      ,sum(Hours) AS Total
 From  YourTable
 Group By Emp_ID